# Is there a default value when the bits for `O_ASYNC`, `O_SYNC` and `O_DIRECT`are not specified in the flag for open(2)?

Tags: c, storage

I'm trying to get details on how information is written for deployed applications.

I gathered the flags from the file descriptors in `/proc/<pid>/fdinfo` but the bits for these are mostly not specified.

I'm wondering whether a default value is used when not specified... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any bits you don't set will be `0`.

Comment: So the default is not async, not sync, and not direct. When you write, it will be buffered in the kernel and `write()` will then return immediately. There won't be a `SIGIO` signal when buffer space becomes available.